# How to rotate a vertex group accordingly to a specific face from that group? (not manual rotation)

Tags: modeling, vertex-groups

I want to make an edge (highlighted with green) parallel to X axis (red arrow) and with that to rotate other edges accordingly as a whole.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible.

I would recommend the following to try to achieve the effect that you want:

- In Edit mode, select the edge circled in green.
- Press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected
- In Object mode, select Shift+A > Mesh > Plane

You can use this Plane object to manually line up your object.

- In Object mode, set your Pivot Point to 3D cursor:

[image]

You can now rotate your original object around the edge highlighted in green, until the edge lines up with the plane object. If you Zoom in as far as possible you should be able to get this perfect. Don't forget to hold Shift while rotating to making smaller changes.

Once done you can delete your plane object.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Although I am practicing in making game assets, so I just wanted to find a solution for when I messed my geometry up and didn't notice that. And I thought I could make some fast adjustment in order not to start sketching forms again. Manual adjustments aren't good I guess for that purpose. I thought something like "s > z > 0" could work, but seems there's no option to adjust other geometry accordingly, as you mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: You could also make sure that the two vertices at the ends of that line have exactly the same 'Z' value when rotating the object. Certainly a bit of a fiddle though!

Comment: @DmitryGuskov zooming in, in the orthographic view, will definitely give you enough precision when rotating - basically just put a line that goes from the right vert left parallel to X axis, and now rotate so your face/edge of choice aligns with it. Otherwise you can use maths, and e.g. take the Z difference between the verts, divide by the length of the edge, pass to arcsine and now you have the angle to rotate everything by...